# clone div's children using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

Im cloning a div multiple times and I need to change its inner children div's as well. (e.g. id_j1, id_j2 etc.)

I manage to clone the whole div and change its id but not the children's ids.

**javascript**

```
document.getElementById('btn_new_service').onclick = duplicate;
var i =0;
function duplicate() {
    var original = document.getElementById('duplicator');
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.id = "duplicator" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID} 
original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
```

if i append the code below in the above code then i get an error of `Uncaught TypeError: clone.children is not a function`.

```
var new_div_ID = 'duplicator-' + i;
var new_service_ID = 'c_service-'+i;
var new_vat_ID = 'vat-'+i;
var new_amount_ID = 'amount-'+i;
var new_vatamount_ID = 'vat_amount-'+i;
clone.children('#c_service').attr('id',new_service_ID);
clone.children('#vat').attr('id',new_vat_ID);
clone.children('#amount').attr('id',new_amount_ID);
clone.children('#vat_amount').attr('id',new_vatamount_ID);
```

i took both of them from 2 different code snippets which they were working fine but when i combine them only they don't. Any tips why does that happens?

Comment: it looks like a `jQuery/DOMApi` meltin pot...

Comment: `$(clone).children(` as Native DOM element doesn't have the function

Comment: @Satpal i need to change the id of the children as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if i append the code below in the above code then i get an error of
>   Uncaught TypeError: clone.children is not a function.

[children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) is not a `function` in vanila js, use `querySelector` instead and `setAttribute` instead

Make it

```
clone.querySelector('#c_service').setAttribute('id',new_service_ID);
```

Comment: thanks man! that works like a charm, so the other one wasn't working because it is not a built in function right? i thought about that but because the original example was declaring a variable clone and making it equal to the main div and after it was using the `children` to change the children's ids

Comment: @noel293 `children` is not a member method of `Node` object as I have mentioned in the answer. Which is why you were getting that error.